# During date parsing in JAVA-8 to specific format. Error is not showing for source(yyyy-MM-dd) and destination(yyyyMMdd) format not matching

Tags: java, date, parsing

Why 2023-01-01 is being accepted for yyyyMMdd format ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String s = "2023-01-01";

    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    sdf.parse(s);
}
```

If the format provided : `yyyy/MM/dd` --> working as expected (throwing exception)

If the format provided : `yyy-MM-dd` ---> Not working as expected ( Not throwing exception )

I can handle this problem by considering the length of string. Question here is why `yyyy-MM-dd` format is being parsed successfully for `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: The [documentation for the `parse` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)) doesn't say it will throw an exception on a string that doesn't respect the provided format. Even just because of this you should use the newer time API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/133203).

Comment: You can make The DateFormatter more strict by disabling lenient parsing via `sdf.setLenient(false);` - Howeverthere ar eprobably a lot of other cases where the old Date classes will not work how you want them to and as already said the best solution would be switching to the newer java.time API.

Comment: In case you were curious: `SimpleDateFormat` took 2023 to be the year, -0 to be the month and 1 to be the day of the month. It does not disturb it that there is no month 0 (-0 is equal to 0). It then ignored the trailing -01. Very confusing indeed. I concur: Do not use that class. Not ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `LocalDate.parse( "2023-01-01" )`

Moot question. You are using terribly flawed date-time classes. These were years ago supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. There is no point in struggling to understand those legacy classes like `SimpleDateFormat`. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those failed classes, and so should you.

Using *java.time* is utterly simple:

```
String s = "2023-01-01";
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( s );
```

No need to specify a formatting pattern. The *java.time* classes use your expanded [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by default.

If your input text is in the compact  “basic” variation of ISO 8601, use the [provided formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20230101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

To detect unexpected or faulty input, trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: Here the input to my method will be in format yyyyMMdd. For this if i provide the value like yyyy-MM-dd it’s getting parsed. Ideally it shouldn’t right

Comment: @KarthikCM I didn’t get what you meant by that. What is the difference between *the input to my method* and *the value*? `yyyyMMdd` is built in too: `LocalDate.parse("20230101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`.

Comment: If you are getting the format pattern string `yyyyMMdd` and the date string `2023-01-01` and you want to detect the fact that they don’t match:  `LocalDate.parse("2023-01-01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` to signal that the string cannot be parsed using that format.